# Couchbase rebalance failed

Tags: couchbase

We had an instance of our Couchbase server we had to take down and we did this successfully using graceful failover. However after adding it back and trying to do a rebalance, I get the following error:

```
Rebalance exited with reason {config_sync_failed,
                          {error,
                           {get_compressed_failed,
                            [{'ns_1@ec2-34-xxx-34-250.compute-1.amazonaws.com',
                              timeout}]}}}
```

**UPDATE:**

Tried again getting the following logs:

```
Starting rebalance, KeepNodes = ['ns_1@ec2-34-xxx-34-250.compute-1.amazonaws.com',
                             'ns_1@ec2-35-xxx-164-37.compute-1.amazonaws.com',
                             'ns_1@ec2-35-xxx-172-50.compute-1.amazonaws.com',
                             'ns_1@ec2-35-xxx-54-198.compute-1.amazonaws.com'], EjectNodes = [], Failed over and being ejected nodes = []; no delta recovery nodes


Started rebalancing bucket freedompop-conversion

Rebalance exited with reason {pre_rebalance_janitor_run_failed,
                             ['ns_1@ec2-35-xxx-172-50.compute-1.amazonaws.com']}
```

Could anyone please explain what is going on and how to fix it? I'm at a loss at the moment.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do the CPU use and memory stats look like on your nodes?  Rebalances can be slow or timeout if the rest of the cluster is under heavy load.

Comment: These instances were actually not being used at all. It seems like some type of communication error. At one point one of the instances we brought back up was deciding to be the master node. They knew about each other but unable to communicate correctly. When we shut those instances back down and brought up new ones, they worked correctly with the system.